# How to use thread in jsp?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

I am learning to use the `Thread` class in java and I want to print the numbers 1 to 50  using a Thread every x seconds on my JSP page. I am not able to do it. I am able to do this using a simple java program but I would like to use it in a JSP.

**Demo.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java"  contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<HTML>
  <BODY>
  <%
    for(int i=0;i<=50;i++)
    out.println(i);
  %>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can I achieve my output?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: jsp is meant for presentation alone . should avoid java codes in jsp

Comment: @Evan Knowles  i need it  in my project

Comment: Do you really need to use thread? If you want to print something periodically, you dont need a thread for that?

Comment: @Hirak  i want to print  with sleep.thread()

Comment: Do you need to use threads in JSP specifically? Or are you just using JSP to see the output?

Comment: @Evan Knowles i need to use threads in JSP specifically

Comment: You didnot understand @EvanKnowles' concern. It is really a bad idea to implement Thread.sleep here. What you want is javascript timeout. Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: You can't run a Thread in JSP. Or at least it won't do what you expect.

Comment: A JSP is evaluated on the server in response to a HTTP request, the resulting HTML returned to the client for display.  You cannot have the server change the HTML once it has been returned.  You will need to use JavaScript, which will run on the client

Comment: A thread is something which does an activity at the server side. But JSP is operating on a browser and your Thread in JSP does not really make sense. As Hirak mentioned, what you'd probably need is javascript and if you must go to the server side, you might make an AJAX call every x seconds to the server to print something.

Comment: i need  to print  1 to 50 number  in every sec  thats it how can i gt this

Comment: Voting to close - the question shows a lack of understanding about the Java web-stack and is, imho, unlikely to be of use

Comment: how can i get my output

Comment: @user3585120 What part of 'JavaScript' didn't you understand? You've been told four times.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has already mentioned in the comments above this cannot be achieved using the `Thread` class in java. But if you want to do it in Javascript, something similar to the below can be used;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">  

<div id="num"><div>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
   document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=1;
   setInterval(function() {document.getElementById("num").innerHTML=Number(document.getElementById("num").innerHTML)+1},1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```